# Simple line translation

Tags: php

My question is rather simple. I have downloaded a script, an online manga reader, and I have translated most of it to my language (Spanish). Now this part is the one that I need to translate:

[image]

I want to translate the word "Page:" but I can't really find it, and since im a newbie when it comes to coding, I was hoping someone would be able to make sence out of this, here's the code:

```
<!-- PAGE BY PAGE -->
<div class="chapter-content"><div class="custom-container-readchapter">
    <?
        $img = explode("http://", $thisChapter['content']);
        $imgs = count($img);
        $img_type = '1';
        $img_display = 'http://';
        if($imgs == '1'){ 
            $img = explode("app/manga/uploads", $thisChapter['content']);
            $imgs = count($img);
            $img_type = '2';
            $img_display = 'app/manga/uploads';
            if($imgs == '1'){
                $img = explode("app/manga/uploads", $thisChapter['content']);
                $imgs = count($img);
                $img_type = '3';
                $img_display = 'https://';
            }
        }   
        page_select($page,$img,$thisChapter);
        $next_page = $page+1;
        $prev_page = $page-1;
        if($next_page > $imgs){
            // Comment box :)
            include 'chapter.comment.php';
        }else{
            echo "<a href='$lang[read_slug]-$slug-$lang[chapter_slug]-$thisChapter[chapter]-$lang[page_slug]-$next_page.html'><img src='".$img_display.$img[$page]."' class='chapter-img'></a>";
            echo "<img src='".$img_display.$img[$page+1]."' style='display:none'>";
        }
        echo '<br /><br />';
        page_select($page,$img,$thisChapter);
    ?>
</div></div>
<!-- KEYBOARD NAVIGATION -->
<script>
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
  // handle cursor keys
  if (event.keyCode == 37) {  
    window.location.href = '<?php echo "$lang[read_slug]-$slug-$lang[chapter_slug]-$thisChapter[chapter]-$lang[page_slug]-$prev_page.html"; ?>';
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    window.location.href = '<?php echo "$lang[read_slug]-$slug-$lang[chapter_slug]-$thisChapter[chapter]-$lang[page_slug]-$next_page.html"; ?>';
  }
}); 
</script>
<!-- END PAGE BY PAGE -->
```

Comment: It is probably being inserted by Javascript elsewhere, there is no select dropdown code or label in that code at all.

Comment: Is it in the `page_select` function?

Comment: Yes it was the page_select which i found in my theme functions.php file, thank you Josiah